# From mysql to eloquent query (Resolved)

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-10

I ran a query in mysql and now I wanted to set it in laravel and I converted it to eloquent, but the result is an error I don't understand why on phpmyadmin the query works and when I convert it to use it in laravel it gives me an error

I also tried using this tool for conversion but it doesn't work

https://jjlabajo.github.io/SQLtoEloquent/

```
SELECT ticket, 
SUM(MINUTE(time_stamp)) 
AS minutes, 
SUM(MINUTE(time_stamp))/60 
AS hours, 
SUM(MINUTE(time_stamp))/(60*24) 
AS days, 
SUM(MINUTE(time_stamp))/(60*24*7) 
AS week
FROM `tickets
GROUP BY ticket

$tickets = DB::table('tickets')
        ->select('ticket', "sum(minute(time_stamp)) as minutes", "sum(minute(time_stamp))/60 as hours", "sum(minute(time_stamp))/ (60*24) as days", "sum(minute(time_stamp))/ (60*24*7) as week")
        ->groupBy("ticket")
        ->get();
```

The error generated is this:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sum(minute(time_stamp))' in 'field list'

Comment: hi, looks like there is a syntax issue in the mentioned. try this way ---->>> `$tickets = DB::table('tickets')
    ->select('ticket', 
             DB::raw("SUM(MINUTE(time_stamp)) as minutes"), 
             DB::raw("(SUM(MINUTE(time_stamp))/60) as hours"), 
             DB::raw("(SUM(MINUTE(time_stamp))/60/24) as days"), 
             DB::raw("(SUM(MINUTE(time_stamp))/60/24/7) as weeks"))
    ->groupBy("ticket")
    ->get();`

Comment: thanks for the reply, now tell me
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'SUM(MINUTE(time_stamp))/60)' in 'field list'

Comment: $tickets = DB::table('tickets')
        ->select('ticket', DB::raw("SUM(MINUTE(time_stamp)) as minute"),
                ("SUM(MINUTE(time_stamp)) as hours"),
                ("SUM(MINUTE(time_stamp)) as days"),
                ("SUM(MINUTE(time_stamp)) as week"))
        ->groupBy('ticket')
        ->get();     SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'SUM(MINUTE(time_stamp))' in 'field list'

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect kindly run the query posted above and try once